# customize actionbar sherlock tabs and dropdownlist

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to customize the style of the tabs BELOW the actionbar. 
For the actionbar I'm using the

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar
```

but the tabs should have a white background and black textcolor. I also want to set a different backgroundcolor for the dropdownlist for the actionbar.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This website generates the theme for you that changes tabs, you can look and see how its done or just use the theme and assets this thing generates. http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator